# DateTimePicker control adding functionality upon focus

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datetimepicker

I'm just looking to see if the functionality I would like to add to the `DateTimePicker` control is actually possible.

What I would like to do is upon the user tabbing to the `DateTimePicker` having the date picker drop down appear so they can start entering the date rather than having to click the arrow to make the date picker appear.

I haven't seen anything on this from MSDN but I may have missed it, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Programmatically open the calendar of the DateTimePicker control](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/winforms/thread/f2f0b213-d57a-46de-b924-e21b7ac0882e), you can try this:

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_Enter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
                                  Handles DateTimePicker1.Enter
  SendKeys.Send("%{DOWN}")
End Sub
```

To tab through the drop down, try something like this:

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                    ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) _
                                    Handles DateTimePicker1.KeyDown
  If e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
    SendKeys.Send("%{F4}")
    Me.SelectNextControl(DateTimePicker1, True, True, True, True)        
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Opening the date picker works great, would there be a way to close it if the user decides to tab past the control? Currently, it opens fine but won't let me tab through it unless a date is picked.  I've tried sending the Esc key through code to cancel the date picker and tab ahead but can't seem to get that to work fine.  Is there another SendKey to close the date picker as well?

Comment: I'm having troubles with it tabbing, it's still having the date picker calendar active. Perhaps if I were to understand what exactly keys that I'm sending are doing with the datepicker control I may better understand what's going on.  What is ("%{DOWN}") and ("%{F4}") doing to the control exactly?  Is there a link somewhere I could research with?

Comment: @Criel Down is the down arrow key, which if you press it on a DateTimePicker control will drop down the calendar.  F4 is, well, F4, which closes the calendar if it is open.  This code worked for me where I also had tabable controls on the form, too.

Answer (score 1):

in C# you can create a extension to DropDown the DateTimePicker, i apologize who created this because i totally forgot :D

```
public static void OpenDateTime(this DateTimePicker obj)
        {
            const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
            int width = obj.Width - 10;
            int height = obj.Height / 2;
            int lParam = width + height * 0x00010000; // VooDoo to shift height
            PostMessage(obj.Handle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 1, lParam);
        }
```

The usage:

```
private void dateTimePicker1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dateTimePicker1.OpenDateTime();
}
```

here's the VB .NET, first you need to create a Module and paste this code

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module Module1
    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Function PostMessage(hwnd As IntPtr, wMsg As Int32, wParam As Int32, lParam As Int32) As Integer
    End Function
    <Extension()>
    Public Sub OpenDateTime(obj As DateTimePicker)
        Const WM_LBUTTONDOWN As Integer = &H201
        Dim width As Integer = obj.Width - 10
        Dim height As Integer = obj.Height / 2
        Dim lParam As Integer = width + height * &H10000
        PostMessage(obj.Handle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 1, lParam)
    End Sub
End Module
```

and the usage is:

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_Enter(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.Enter
    DateTimePicker1.OpenDateTime()
End Sub
```

and that`s it :)